# How to convert epoch time to Date object in Swift 5.0?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, epoch

I am trying to convert an epoch time to Date object. But I am getting wrong value.

My epoch time is this **1586863971924**

My code is :

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1586863971924)

  print("date - \(date)")
```

**Output:**

```
date - 52255-09-20 03:45:24 +0000
```

When I am using this link https://www.epochconverter.com/ to convert this epoch time the I am getting this output:

[image]

Why my code is showing wrong answer. Suggest me how to convert this epoch time to correct date object.

Comment: You should use a number 1000 times smaller: `1586863971.924`.

Comment: In this image the text bolded milliseconds, but `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)` accept seconds parameter, so before passing it, convert from milliseconds to seconds

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper and zzmasoud